# pad block corrupted apex Crypto

Tags: apex, rest-api, customsetting, encryption

I am facing an issue while decryption of value which is stored in custom setting.
When i encrypt and decrypt value at same time then i that error is not thrown, if i get the value from custom setting, this error is thrown.

below is my code while does not gives error:

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

        Blob data = Blob.valueOf('svcx-help-salesforce@xxxx.com');
        Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
        system.debug('encryptedData :' + encryptedData);
        String encryptString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
        system.debug('encryptedData 2:' + encryptString);



        Blob data2 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encryptString);
        Blob decryptedUsername = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data2);
        String decryptedClearText = decryptedUsername.toString();
        System.debug(decryptedClearText);
```

Below code when i get the value from custom setting:

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

        ConnectTranslationAPI__c connect = ConnectTranslationAPI__c.getValues('GenerateToken');
        String username = connect.Username__c;
        username = username.trim();
        System.debug(username);

        Blob data2 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(username);
        Blob decryptedUsername = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data2);
        String decryptedClearText = decryptedUsername.toString();
        System.debug(decryptedClearText);
```

I tried replace the value in custom setting with the new encryption key. still i get this error

Can you please help me out.

Comment: Please do not use the `[community]` tag unless you are asking a question about the **[`Communities`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_overview.htm&type=5)** feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of two things, I believe, is happening here.

If your code as shown in your question is exactly what you're using, the problem is that you're generating a brand-new AES key every time you try to access an encrypted value.

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
```

That won't work. If you encrypt Value A with Key B to yield Ciphertext C, you have to store and reload Key A in order to decrypt Ciphertext C. Some other Key Q that you generate has no relationship to that ciphertext - that's the whole point of encryption.

The other possibility is that you are correctly storing and using a single key, but the code that stores encrypted values (which you haven't shown here) is either mangling or truncating the ciphertext. I previously wrote an [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240180/crypto-class-error-pad-block-corrupted/240184#240184) demonstrating how such errors arise from ciphertext corruption.

Comment: It was the Key issue. I din't realized that every time it used to generate a new key. Storing the key as well now. Thank you.