# how to provide username and password in test method for REST API

Tags: unit-test, rest-api, apexrest

**apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: pad block corrupted**

```
if (req.headers.get('username') != null&&req.headers.get('password')!=null && Authorization.decrypt(req.headers.get('username'),req.headers.get('password'){
        for(Visit vf : VisitsDataList){
            if(vf.ActionName!=null&&vf.ActionName!=''){
                visitActionMap.put(vf.Id,vf.ActionName);
                if(actionMapVisitIds.containsKey(vf.ActionName)){
                    actionMap

VisitIds.get(vf.ActionName).add(vf.Id);
                } else {
                    actionMapVisitIds.put(vf.ActionName, new List<String{vf.Id});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Test Class**

```
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);     
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField('listVisitsData', visitList);
        gen.writeEndObject();   

       String json =gen.getAsString();  
       system.debug('@@@@@ '+json);    


Test.startTest();    
    RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
    RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

    String username ='EmpApp';
    String password ='2ZnGZayPcs0t+yfu5rciKNGlO7Ogx4QJ0puSu7+I9e6ykZfJL4NGrMrogBxBxrK3';

    req.requestURI = 'https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/getVisitDetails/';  
    req.httpMethod = 'POST';  
    req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      
    req.addHeader('username', username);
    req.addHeader('password', password); 

    req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(json);
    RestContext.request = req;
    RestContext.response = res;    

    WS_GetVisitDetails.getVisitDetails();
Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(json); No variable called json in your code?

Comment: @nube i added Json string

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear what the issue is with which you'd like assistance. If you have an error, include it verbatim with line number. Right now, all we can see is that you seem to have written the code to do what your question's title says already.

Comment: apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: pad block corrupted getting this Error

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the specific **error message and line**. Comments are not for providing extra information.

Comment: @DavidReed i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: pad block corrupted

This message means that your ciphertext (the value of `username`, apparently) is corrupted or is not valid ciphertext. I discussed this at greater length in [a previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240180/crypto-class-error-pad-block-corrupted/240184#240184); the short summary is that your ciphertext may have had a character altered or removed, or has such a mutation performed in your decryption code.

It looks like you are providing a base64-encoded cryptographic key in `password` and an encrypted value in `username`. However, the value you're showing in `username` in your unit test is in plaintext, which won't be able to be decrypted successfully.

However your `Authorization` class is implemented, you'll need to generate a real, valid ciphertext and password pair to populate in your unit test.